Copying an item next to the item does not work accordingly
I have an array of objects with the following format
const [type1Options, setType1Options] = useState([
  {
    name: "Name1",
    value: "Value1",
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    value: "Value2",
  },
]);

const [type2Options, setType2Options] = useState([
  {
    name: "Name1",
    value: "Value1",
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    value: "Value2",
  },
]);

I am rendering these objects category wise with copy and delete buttons per entry. Delete will delete the entry from the array, and copy will copy the clicked items content into a new entry and placed right below the clicked entry. Delete works just fine, but copy on the last entry doesn't work as expected. Can someone help?
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/i18-demo-7594gf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A5%2C2-24%2C6
Utils for copy and delete functions
export const deleteItems = (list, idx) => {
  const temp = [...list];
  temp.splice(idx, 1);
  return temp;
};

export const copyItems = (list, idx) => {
  const newItem = { ...list[idx] };
  const newItems = [...list.slice(0, idx + 1), newItem, ...list.slice(idx + 1)];
  return newItems;
};

import { useState } from "react";
import List from "./List";

export default function App() {
  const [type1Options, setType1Options] = useState([
    {
      name: "Name1",
      value: "Value1",
    },
    {
      name: "Name2",
      value: "Value2",
    },
  ]);

  const [type2Options, setType2Options] = useState([
    {
      name: "Name1",
      value: "Value1",
    },
    {
      name: "Name2",
      value: "Value2",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <List
        type1Options={type1Options}
        type2Options={type2Options}
        setType1Options={setType1Options}
        setType2Options={setType2Options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

import Type1 from "./Type1";
import Type2 from "./Type2";

export default function List(props) {
  const { type1Options, type2Options, setType1Options, setType2Options } =
    props;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Category 1
        {type1Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type1
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            type1Options={type1Options}
            setType1Options={setType1Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        Category 2
        {type2Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type2
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            type2Options={type2Options}
            setType1Options={setType2Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

import "./styling.css";
import { deleteItems, copyItems } from "./utils";

export default function Type1(props) {
  const { index, obj, type1Options, setType1Options } = props;

  const copyHandler = () => setType1Options(copyItems(type1Options, index + 1));

  const deleteHandler = (index) =>
    setType1Options(deleteItems(type1Options, index + 1));

  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="box-header">
        <h3>Index {index + 1}</h3>
        <div className="box-buttons">
          <button onClick={copyHandler}>Copy</button>
          <button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="box-content">
        {obj.name}: {obj.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Issue was the mismatch of 1 and 2 in type1Options and type2Options in 2 files. here is the updated code.
List.jsx
import Type1 from "./Type1";
import Type2 from "./Type2";

export default function List(props) {
  const { type1Options, type2Options, setType1Options, setType2Options } =
    props;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Category 1
        {type1Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type1
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            type1Options={type1Options}
            setType1Options={setType1Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        Category 2
        {type2Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type2
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            type2Options={type2Options}
            setType2Options={setType2Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

and type2.jsx
import React from "react";
import "./styling.css";
import { deleteItems, copyItems } from "./utils";

export default function Type2(props) {
  const { index, obj, type2Options, setType2Options } = props;

  const copyHandler = () => setType2Options(copyItems(type2Options, index));

  const deleteHandler = () => setType2Options(deleteItems(type2Options, index));

  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="box-header">
        <h3>Index {index + 1}</h3>
        <div className="box-buttons">
          <button onClick={copyHandler}>Copy</button>
          <button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="box-content">
        {obj.name}: {obj.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

@DrewReese ok i edited my answer.

Issues

The Type2 component is passing index + 1 to the utility functions and copying/deleting the wrong array element.
const copyHandler = () =>
  setType1Options(copyItems(type2Options, index + 1));

const deleteHandler = (index) =>
  setType1Options(deleteItems(type2Options, index + 1));


The Type1 and Type2 components fail to pass the array index to the delete utility function, they instead are passing the onClick event object and the wrong element is removed from the source array.
const deleteHandler = (index) => // <-- onClick event object
  setType1Options(deleteItems(type1Options, index));

...

<button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>



Solution/Suggestions

Pass the current index value to correctly copy or delete the array element at that index.
Don't pass the onClick event object through to utility function.

const copyHandler = () =>
  setType1Options(copyItems(type2Options, index));

const deleteHandler = () =>
  setType1Options(deleteItems(type2Options, index)); // <-- index from props

Additional tips/fixes/etc

You should also use functional state updates to correctly update from the previous state instead of whatever is closed over in callback scope.
The mapped options are missing a React key. I suggest adding an id property to the options to uniquely identify them, especially since you are mutating the array by adding and removing elements. This should help avoid any React rendering issues.
There is also a prop naming "mismatch" in Type2 where the setter is named like it's the Type1 component setter, i.e. setType1Options instead of setType2Options. There is no bug here, but the naming convention could be confusing to future readers/maintainers of your code.

App.jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import List from "./List";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid"; // <-- generate GUIDs

export default function App() {
  const [type1Options, setType1Options] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(), // <-- generate GUID
      name: "Name1",
      value: "Value1",
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(), // <-- generate GUID
      name: "Name2",
      value: "Value2",
    },
  ]);

  const [type2Options, setType2Options] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(), // <-- generate GUID
      name: "Name1",
      value: "Value1",
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(), // <-- generate GUID
      name: "Name2",
      value: "Value2",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <List
        type1Options={type1Options}
        type2Options={type2Options}
        setType1Options={setType1Options}
        setType2Options={setType2Options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

utils.ts
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export const deleteItems = (list, idx) => {
  const temp = [...list];
  temp.splice(idx, 1);
  return temp;
};

export const copyItems = (list, idx) => {
  const newItem = {
    ...list[idx],
    id: nanoid(), // <-- generate new id for copied element
  };

  return [
    ...list.slice(0, idx + 1),
    newItem,
    ...list.slice(idx + 1)
  ];
};

List.jsx
export default function List({
  type1Options,
  type2Options,
  setType1Options,
  setType2Options,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Category 1
        {type1Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type1
            key={obj.id} // <-- use id as React key
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            setType1Options={setType1Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        Category 2
        {type2Options.map((obj, index) => (
          <Type2
            key={obj.id} // <-- use id as React key
            index={index}
            obj={obj}
            setType2Options={setType2Options}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Type1.jsx
export default function Type1({ index, obj, setType1Options }) {
  const copyHandler = () =>
    setType1Options((type1Options) => copyItems(type1Options, index));

  const deleteHandler = () =>
    setType1Options((type1Options) => deleteItems(type1Options, index));

  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="box-header">
        <h3>Index {index + 1}</h3>
        <div className="box-buttons">
          <button onClick={copyHandler}>Copy</button>
          <button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="box-content">
        {obj.name}: {obj.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Type2.jsx
export default function Type2({ index, obj, setType2Options }) {
  const copyHandler = () =>
    setType2Options((type2Options) => copyItems(type2Options, index));

  const deleteHandler = () =>
    setType2Options((type2Options) => deleteItems(type2Options, index));

  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="box-header">
        <h3>Index {index + 1}</h3>
        <div className="box-buttons">
          <button onClick={copyHandler}>Copy</button>
          <button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="box-content">
        {obj.name}: {obj.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

